# Spinning card animation displaying reverse side incorrectly

Tags: rendering, animation, mesh

I'm attempting to create a trading card design in Blender (version 3.1.2) and animate it to spin for 4 seconds. I am importing 2 files, .png files with transparent background, and importing them as planes. One image for the front of the card, one for the back. I placed both of the cards parallel to each other, and successfully animated it.

My problem now is during animation, while it spins, only one side shows, and when it rotates to the back of the card, it displays a reversed image of the same side. I will try to attach some images to better show the issue I'm facing.

[image: Front of card]

Front of the card

[image: Rear of card]

Rear of the card

[image: What is displayed as it spins. Notice this is frame 64/120, so back image should be displayed]

What is displayed as it spins. Notice this is frame 64/120, so back image should be displayed

Edit: Thank you for all of your help and answers everyone! I have tried to implement some of the solutions Robin, Lukasz and Marty mentioned. I added a cube, shaped it into a card form, and aligned my two faces on top of the plane and animated it, however, it seems the problem I'm running into is all three elements rotate around the same axis, so only one face is displaying itself. I uploaded the .blend for you guys to take a peek, thank you kindly and sorry for my poor knowledge of blender, I'm more of a coder than a graphic designer!

https://pasteall.org/blend/efec531fc8cf43ccb4fe43327016f57c

Comment: pls upload blend file so we can check it out. thanks

Comment: looks like the second card is not being rendered.  If you them in the same position it's probably due to Z fighting.  Separate them by a small distance.  Double check to make sure the card is not disabled in render.

Comment: as you can read in the comments and the answer of Robin - we don't know what you did and we are just guessing around what the reason could be. So please improve your answer with additional informations.

Answer (score 1):

Your post indicates you don't mind having an infinitely-thin card?

If so, putting 2 planes in the same place will create a floating-point  contest for the renderer (Z-fighting), as @Marty Fouts has commented.

Instead, you could use one plane, and select the image according to whether its normal is facing towards or away from you, using the *Geometry* node's > 'Backfacing' output:

[image]

[image]

If the card has thickness, though, you could give each side separate materials / maybe use the 'Material Index' feature of the *Solidify* modifier, or use the direction of the normal in the card's Object texture coordinates, to select the image used, in one material.

Answer (score 0):

Or, to make it realistic, add **a cube**, scale it to give the card a little thickness, bevel it and apply your image textures - one to the front, the other to the back face of the cube. This is time and cost -efficient and gives the desired effect.